# More than one delivery location

Tags: prison-architect

Playing Alpha 23 on Linux. Is it possible to have 2 or more Delivery Rooms? I set up a second prison complex with its own Delivery Room but all deliveries still only go to the first Delivery Room. This causes all the cooks and workers to travel to the first Delivery Room.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version as of writing this answer (Alpha 29) the truck unloading was overhauled. Trucks will now deliver their goods to the closest delivery location as soon as they stop. However, the unloading AI doesn't know where the goods are supposed to go, so you have no way to control into which delivery area specific goods are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible (according to my own experience and the [official wiki](http://devwiki.introversion.co.uk/pa/index.php/Deliveries)). Also, a quick search on the [PA bugtracker](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view_all_bug_page.php) did not found any bugs related to this.